# OpenXml - Find the index of the first Run element in a paragraph

Tags: c#, openxml

I'm trying to use the wordprocessing `InsertAt` method on a paragraph, but my paragraph styling was always being set to null when I used this method. I found the index I was using, 0, was for the ParagraphProperties and Run was at index 1. However, when there are no paragraph properties set, the only child element Paragraph has is Run

Is there a consistent way of finding the index Run is at? Or will it always be at either 0 or 1?

Code snippet for context

```
var run = new W.Run() { RunProperties = new W.RunProperties() { NoProof = new W.NoProof() } };
run.AppendChild(dr);

para.InsertAt(run, 0);
```

Obviously I can just do something like `Math.Min(1, para.Count - 1)` but I'm unsure if any other elements could be added to the paragraph and the Run element ends up being the middle element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A paragraph can contain multiple Runs. For example:

```
<w:p xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
  <w:r>
    <w:t>Some text</w:t>
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:noProof />
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>Other text</w:t>
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:t>Last text in paragraph</w:t>
  </w:r>
</w:p>
```

So the answer to your question really depends on what you want to accomplish. Based on your answer, it looks like you want to add a new `Run` before a run that is already in the `Paragraph`.

The `Paragraph` class has some methods that are usefull like `InsertBefore`, `InsertAfter`, etc, fx:

```
Paragraph p = ...
Run r = new Run(...);
p.InsertBefore(r, p.GetFirstChild<Run>());
```

This will make r the first `Run` in the paragraph - assuming there is already a `Run` in the paragraph.

You can try 'looking inside' some example word documents by using OpenXML Productivity Tool.

Comment: Yeah I realised there could be multiple Runs, I was looking for the first one... updated question title to reflect that :) 

So what's the difference between `para.InsertAt(run, indexOfFirstRun)` and `para.InsertBefore(run, para.GetFirstChild<Run>())`? The InsertAt method seems to be inserting before the index provided (or rather moving everything else down, and inserting it at that index)

Comment: I'm still not sure why `InsertAt` at the index of ParagraphProperties nulls the properties, but works fine if you insert at the index of a Run

Answer (score 0):

I've done it the 'long' way for now, if there's a cleaner solution I'm all ears...

```
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < para.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (para.ElementAt(i) is W.Run)
            {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        para.InsertAt(run, index);
```